# Updating React State only changes current row in table, not the updated rows in state

Tags: reactjs

I built a table and I made a child component for a row.  When I update the state in the  component, only the current row is being re-rendered.  Not the child rows that had the state change.  Inside the collapseRow function, I am looping over all the children that need to be hidden, and setting them to isHidden = true.

The console.log on TableRow.jsx:54 is showing row1.  I would expect it to show {"id": "row2", .... "isHidden": true}

Clearly I am not updating the state properly, but I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

```
    {
        "id": "row1",
        "children": [
            "row2",
            "row3",
            "row4"
        ],
        "isHidden": false,
    }
```

```
    import {React, useState, useEffect} from "react";
    import axios from "axios";
    import TableRow from "../../components/TableRow/TableRow";
    import './pmo.css';
    
    export default function PMO() {
        const[headerData, setHeaderData] = useState([]);
        const[rowData, setRowData] = useState({});
    
        useEffect(
            () => {
                axios.get('PmoData.json')
                    .then(function (response) {
                        setRowData(response['data'].rows);
                        setHeaderData(response['data'].headers);
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    })
            }
        , []);
        console.log(rowData);
    
    
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Project Management</h1>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            {headerData && Object.keys(headerData).map((headerKey,i)=>{
                                return (<th key={headerKey}>{headerData[headerKey]}</th>)
                            })}
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {rowData && Object.keys(rowData).map((rowKey,i)=>{
                            console.log(rowKey + " "+ rowData[rowKey]['isHidden']);
                            return (
                                <TableRow key={rowKey} row={rowData[rowKey]} setRowData={setRowData} rowData={rowData} />
                            )
                        })}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Child component:

```
    import { React, useEffect, useState, } from "react";
    import {BsChevronDown, BsChevronUp} from "react-icons/bs";
    
    export default function TableRow({row, setRowData, rowData}) {
        const[rowColor, setRowColor] = useState('');
        const[textColor, settextColor] = useState('');
        const[collapsibleIcon, setCollapsibleIcon] = useState(true);
        const[showCollapsibleIcon, setShowCollapsibleIcon] = useState(false);
    
        useEffect(
            () => {
                setRowColor(row.color)
                settextColor(row.textColor)
                row && Object.keys(row).map(function(keyName, keyIndex) {
                    if(row['collapsible'] === 'true') {
                        setShowCollapsibleIcon(true);
                    }
    
                    return null;
                })
            } , [row]
        );
    
        function collapseRow(children) {
            if (collapsibleIcon){
                setCollapsibleIcon(false);
                children && children.map( (child) => {
                    rowData && Object.keys(rowData).map((rowKey,i)=>{
                        if(rowKey === child) {
                            return rowData[rowKey] = { ...rowData[rowKey], isHidden: true };
                        }
                        setRowData(rowData[rowKey]);
                        return null;
                    })
                    return null;
                });
                setRowData(rowData);
            } else {
                setCollapsibleIcon(true);
                children && children.map( (child) => {
                    rowData && Object.keys(rowData).map((rowKey,i)=>{
                        if(rowKey === child) {
                            return rowData[rowKey] = { ...rowData[rowKey], isHidden: false };
                        }
                        return null;
                    })
                    return null;
                });
                setRowData(rowData);
            }
        }
    
        console.log("We should be here right " );
        console.log(row);
        if (row.isHidden === true) {
            return null;
        }
    
        return (
            <tr
                style={{backgroundColor: rowColor, color: textColor }}
                id={row.id}
            >
                <td onClick={() => collapseRow(row.children)}>
                    {showCollapsibleIcon && collapsibleIcon && <BsChevronDown/>}
                    {showCollapsibleIcon && !collapsibleIcon && <BsChevronUp/>}
                </td>
                {row && Object.keys(row).map(function(keyName, keyIndex) {
                    if(
                        keyName !== 'color'
                        && keyName !== 'textColor'
                        && keyName !== 'collapsible'
                        && keyName !== 'id'
                        && keyName !== 'children'
                    ) {
                        return(
                            <td key={keyName}>{row[keyName]}</td>
                        )
                    }
                    return null;
                })}
            </tr>
        );
    }
```